# cytoscape.js for PPI jsmol. Main difference between cytoscape.js and cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I want to implement a web application for PPI and 3D strucutres.
Anyone know if cytoscape.js is better than cytoscape ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a sound knowledge about exporting data to JSON format and pass it through cytoscape parameters.

The documentation is self-explanatory for that. 
Note that cystoscape.js and jsmol is two different thing. I suggest that you start with cytoscape first for generation of molecular networks.

Source: Bioinformatics Expert from Functional Genomics Center Zurich

Comment: Baadshah thanks for your comment. I would like to know if you have tried this before and what about the learning curve for cytoscape.js.
I dont have much time to implement such a system.

Thanks

Comment: If you can use jQuery, you can use Cytoscape.js.  The APIs are analogous in most cases.  Cytoscape.js handles all the grunt work for you in terms of gesture support etc, so you can just focus on your app itself.